# Is there a software like Nokia Ovi Suite for syncing Nokia symbian phones with GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, synchronization

I have been looking unsuccessfully for many days for a nice linux software similar to the Nokia Ovi Suite or Nokia PC Suite for syncing Messages, Contacts etc in Ubuntu/Fedora.

There were rumors about a 'Nokia Ovi Suite for linux' in Nokia Beta Labs. But it didn't exist last time I checked.

It is really inefficient to switch to windows time and again just to sync my phone.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

[Gammu](http://wammu.eu/phones/nokia/) and [Gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/docs.shtml#symbian) have support for some Symbian phones - mostly older ones.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried many different options with no joy.
I use the ovi sync feature (pre installed) on my nokia c7, this is done through my wireless connection at home (no charge).  All of my contacts, calendar, and notes can then be accessed through normal browser (Firefox) on Ubuntu.

It does require sign in and so registration is needed.